# Trying to allow nulls but... "Nullable object must have a value"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to allow nulls in my drop down list, in my database table I have set allow nulls for that specific field which is int, but when I run the code I get error saying "Nullable object must have a value", I think problem may be in ModelState.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            Loan w = new Loan()
            {
                StudentID = student.StudentID,
                ISBN = student.ISBN.Value,
            };
            db.Loans.Add(w);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ISBN1 = new SelectList(db.Books, "ISBN", "Titulli", student.ISBN);
        return View(student);
    }
```

Comment: Is `ISBN` property of `Loan` class nullable?

Comment: *Which* nullable object should have a value? When is `ModelState` considered to be valid? At what line in the code do you get that error?

Comment: yes it is, but u now in first time i get that error but if i go back and see the list the changes are saved i dont now what is going on now

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are getting this error when trying to [get value of nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) object, which do not have value. If `Loan.ISBN` property is not nullable then you should provide default value for that property

```
ISBN = student.ISBN.HasValue ? student.ISBN.Value : defaultValue
// or ISBN = student.ISBN ?? defaultValue
// or ISBN = student.ISBN.GetValueOrDefault()
```

If `Loan.ISBN` property is nullable, then simply assign `student.ISBN` without accessing `Value` of nullable type

```
ISBN = student.ISBN
```

Comment: If you set the `Value` property to `null`, then why isn't `HasValue` true? Seems like, since it was explicitly set, it has a value and that value is `null`.

Comment: @toddmo [HasValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates whether nullable object has a valid value of its *underlying type*. `null` is not valid value for `struct` so, `HasValue` by its intent should return false. Also keep in mind that `Value` has type `T` which is `struct` (again, you cannot assign null to value type) and even more - `Value` is read-only property.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest way to perform the same task, using the coalesce operator, ??, shown below:

```
ISBN = student.ISBN ?? defaultValue;
```

The coalesce operator works like this: if the first value (left hand side) is null, then C# evaluates the second expression (right hand side).

Answer (score 5):

This exception occurs when you try to access to the `Value` property of `Nullable` type when `HasValue` is false. See [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN. So first of all check this line

```cs
ISBN = student.ISBN.Value
```

to see whether `ISBN` isn't null. You may want to change this line to

```
ISBN = student.ISBN.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a List of object with a **double?** property. After receiving a request into the controller I could not send the list to the service class and I get error **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'**. I changed the null values to 999999999 (default vlaue) and in service method ignores 999999999 values and insert them to the database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/TestReader/UpdateStudentsGradeFromExcel")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateStudentsGradeFromExcel(List<TestReaderStudentsVM> model)
    {
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            if (item.Grade == null)
                item.Grade = 999999999;
        }
        tblTestReaderManager.UpdateStudentsGradeFromExcel(model);
        return Ok();
    }
```

In service method:

```
foreach (var item in model.Where(m => m.Grade != 999999999))
{
   // insert model items to the db
}
```